# Leaflet side by side always displays layers on the right

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I'm working with [leaflet-sbs](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side) to compare different layers.

```
    <l-map @ready="onMapReady">
      <l-tile-layer v-bind="tilesOpts" />
    </l-map>
```

The map uses one single tile layer based on https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Then I create the sbs element and add a few GEOjson layers (GEODATAx = JSON.parse(geojson)):

```
const sbs = L.control.sideBySide([], []).addTo(map);
const layer1 = L.geoJSON(GEODATA1, { style: { color: 'red', weight: 2, opacity: 1 } }).addTo(map);
const layer2 = L.geoJSON(GEODATA2, { style: { color: 'green', weight: 2, opacity: 1 } }).addTo(map);
const layer3 = L.geoJSON(GEODATA3, { style: { color: 'blue', weight: 2, opacity: 1 } }).addTo(map);
const layer4 = L.geoJSON(GEODATA4, { style: { color: 'yellow', weight: 2, opacity: 1 } }).addTo(map);
```

Then I push the layers to a pane:

```
sbs.setLeftLayers([layer1, layer2]);
```

This works, I get my 2 layers on the left pane. I could use *sbs.setRightLayers* to add them to the right pane instead.

The problem is when I want to add layers on both panes:

```
sbs.setLeftLayers([layer1, layer2]);
sbs.setRightLayers([layer3, layer4]);
```

Only the layers in the right pane are displayed.

I've looked at the github issues and replaced *getContainer* with *getPane* so that the lib works with leaflet 1.9

I've tried setting the layers directly inside L.control.sideBySide method to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found this SE post
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345096/leaflet-compare-two-side-by-side-geojson-layers

I had to create 2 panes:

```
this.map.createPane('left');
this.map.createPane('right');
```

And then for each GEOjson assign the correct pane:

```
const layer = L.geoJSON(map, { style: { color, weight: 2, opacity: 1 }, pane: 'left' }).addTo(this.map);
```

Thank god for this SE post. I was going crazy.